# Catching a function call of a subprocess in python and making adjustments before continuing execution

Tags: python, caching, subprocess, python-sphinx

I have a python script that calls another python program via commandline([sphinx multiversion](https://github.com/Holzhaus/sphinx-multiversion)) using the subprocess module. This program iterates over each open git branch in the current directory and creates a seperate documentation.

I would like to be able to insert a different path into pythonpath to different versions of the same module upon each iteration this program makes. The program makes a subprocess call with the relevant information [here](https://github.com/Holzhaus/sphinx-multiversion/blob/cdc9cb591a738e67a5aacc458f9c95e2b88a94c2/sphinx_multiversion/git.py#L36), is there a way to pause further execution once this call is made, adjust the pythonpath that is globally used across all python instances, and continue execution?

For those who are experienced with sphinx, my initial approach was to create a seperate txt file denoting the path to the version of the module I would like to load in each git branch. The conf.py would then load this path and insert it at the 0th place. Unfortunately this plugin [caches](https://github.com/Holzhaus/sphinx-multiversion/issues/69) the conf.py file from the first branch and then uses it across all subsequent iterations. Is there maybe a better way to achieve my goal of using a different version of the same module? I am using autodoc to document my code and would like my documentation to encompass the differences across the different versions as well.